# Less Css not working on IE8 and IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, less

I have question why Less Css not working (page without applied stylesheets) on this both browsers? On IE9+ it looks normal like on Chrome, FF and Opera too.
Look on screens:

**Source**
[image: Source]
**code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Mansion</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/normalize.css" media="all"/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,700,900,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/Content/siteHD.less"  media="screen and (max-width: 1920px)" />
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/Content/site1024.less"  media="screen and (max-width: 1024px)" />
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/Content/site768.less"  media="screen and (max-width: 768px)" />
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/Content/site640.less"  media="screen and (max-width: 640px)" />
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/Content/site320.less"  media="screen and (max-width: 320px)" />
</head>
<body>...</body>
</html>
```

**IE10 (IE9 look like here)**
[image: IE10]

**IE8** (look on last style which jump over head section)
[image: IE8]

### Are you see here something wrong what I cannot see?

Comment: Tried and nothing change. It looks like nested rules not working. Working only some of them

Comment: Hey WooCaSh if my answer was correct and/or helped you will you please check it for the next person who searches for this question?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are trying to use LESS files on your site without including the `less.js` library, which is required to translate your LESS code into CSS that the browsers can understand.

Download `less.js` from the top of the page at [lesscss.org](http://www.lesscss.org), and then include it just before your `</head>` tag:

```
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Obviously you'll need to change the path to wherever you store the JS file on your website. Please note that this file is to be included *after* your stylesheets.

Example with your posted code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Mansion</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/normalize.css" media="all"/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,700,900,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/Content/siteHD.less"  media="screen and (max-width: 1920px)" />
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/Content/site1024.less"  media="screen and (max-width: 1024px)" />
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/Content/site768.less"  media="screen and (max-width: 768px)" />
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/Content/site640.less"  media="screen and (max-width: 640px)" />
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/Content/site320.less"  media="screen and (max-width: 320px)" />
    <script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>...</body>
</html>
```

On another note, you should probably take a look at compiling your LESS code to one or more CSS files using one of the available compilers. Check out the list of available [GUI compilers that use LESS](https://github.com/less/less.js/wiki/GUI-compilers-that-use-LESS.js).

Comment: Doesn't LESS not compile in browser for IE8 and lower?